# Zoom in zoom out animation

Tags: android, animation

I am testing a zoom in/zoom out animation when an image is clicked. But I didn't get the results I wanted. The image completely zooms in but does not completely zoom out. For better understanding of my problem, see [this video](https://goo.gl/photos/52XwkQGPihzgFXGS7).

Here is my code:

**zoom_in.XML**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fillAfter="true" >
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="3"
    android:toYScale="3" >
</scale>
</set>
```

**zoom_out.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fillAfter="true" >
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5" >
</scale>
```

**mainactivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
 {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageButton pic = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.levelimg);
    pic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogpic);
            dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
  }
```

**my dailog animation style**

```
<style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/zoom_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/zoom_out</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html Is this what you trying?

Comment: If you are trying to take click event of image which have zoom it won't take     proper click of it because animation change only view's UI but not current position so when you click on image which is zoomed it doesn't take click of it

Answer (score 5):

change your code with this.

zoom_in.xml

```
<scale
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:fromXScale="0.3"
    android:fromYScale="0.3"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
```

zoom_out.xml

```
<scale
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0"
    android:toYScale="0" />
```

This will do the trick for you. :)

Comment: Tried as you said but its not zooming in from them center of the image and when back button is pressed its again zooming in and then closing

Comment: if you want your imageview to zoom in zoom out anim, use this library https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations.

Comment: Ya bro I will take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

Change your zoom out code as below and check once,Let me if it is not working.

```
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fillAfter="true" >

        <scale
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:duration="

1000"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="0"
        android:toYScale="0" >
    </scale>
```

Comment: Tried as you said. The zooming in and zoom out are not form the center of the images

Comment: Can you Share the Video ,How it looks now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   private ImageView iv;
   private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
   private float scale = 1f;
   private ScaleGestureDetector SGD;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
      SGD = new ScaleGestureDetector(this,new ScaleListener());
   }

   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
      SGD.onTouchEvent(ev);
      return true;
   }

   private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.

   SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
      @Override
      public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
         scale *= detector.getScaleFactor();
         scale = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scale, 5.0f));

         matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
         iv.setImageMatrix(matrix);
         return true;
      }
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
      // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
      // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

      int id = item.getItemId();

      //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
      if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
         return true;
      }
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```